# How to use search function in ldp.exe to search class (user) attributes (mustcontain)

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I need to admit that I am a beginner with AD DS Schema.

I want to make some user attribute fields required at the time of creating a user account in AD.

I followed the instructions in the article [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/de57f527-82ae-4ca8-9da8-ae0266cab70d/required-field-to-create-user-account?forum=winserverDS). I made a mistake (don't remember which values I set in mustContain attribute) now I can't create an active directory account I would like to query *mustContain* attribute in class= user to find the values in mustContain. I tried ldp.exe search but confuse what parameters in need to use in search function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would need to set up your Base DN to `CN=User,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=...` and Scope to Base. In the Attributes section put `mustContain` or leave asterisk to get all the attributes.